# After applying windows update(KB4565627), Unable to communicate the WCF service from the application

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a WCF service that is hosted at the production server as well as my local machine, Previously I was able to communicate my local WCF service through our Web application(MVC) over the net.tcp as well as the http, but after the installing the update of **KB4565627** (**CVE-2020-1147**) I am not able to communicate and getting the below errors. I have uninstalled the update and tried to communicate again then successfully able to connect the WCF service.

Could you plese help me to resolve the WCF connection issue along with the security update.

Following errors while communicating WCF through Web Application(MVC) :

```
**Through net.tcp** - There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost.company.com/WCFHost/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details

**Through HTTP** - There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost.company.com/WCFHost/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details
```

Please find the attached files for the reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to KB4562900. My computer upgraded to KB4562900 without any problems. Below is the link about KB4562900:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4562900/kb4562900-cumulative-update-for-net-framework

You can also try to rebuild your project and republish to IIS, and finally update the service reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

KB4562900 this update is for windows10 version 1909, but I am having the latest update over the windows 10 version 2004 that is KB4565627.

I need to run the application on the update KB4565627.

I have already tried to build the project and able to run on localhost but when the application tries to connect my WCF through a proxy then getting the above mentioned error.

your help will be much appreciated

Comment: @AkramAhmed Have you fixed this problem, I met a similar problem, but not sure whether it is caused by update kb4565627.